# After using the remote SSH extension on VScode, I can edit files by using nano in the terminal but cannot edit via the VS code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-access

I've tried using the VS code documentation but it didn't help much.
This is what I referred: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting

and also,

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/faq

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I had the vim extension installed because of which I was working in the default "normal" mode.